# Drawing rectangle border is always white (on live camera stream)

Tags: ios, objective-c, opencv

I'm using this function to draw a rectangle on an image (which is not greyscale):

```
cv::rectangle(image, cv::Point(fx1,fy1), cv::Point(fx2,fy2), CV_RGB(0,255,0), +3, CV_AA);
```

The problem is that the border doesn't appear green, but white. In fact is doesn't matter what color parameter I choose - it is always white.

**UPDATE**

The rectangle is drawn on the camera stream, on every frame

```
- (void)processImage:(Mat&)image
```

Could it be a side effect? How can I prevent it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `CV_RGB(0,255,0)` because of the alpha channel.

try this, `cv::Scalar(0,255,0,255)` (R,G,B,Alpha).

```
cv::rectangle(image, cv::Point(fx1,fy1), cv::Point(fx2,fy2), cv::Scalar(0,255,0,255), +3, CV_AA);
```

Comment: Yep, I was missing the alpha. Thanks for that.